# Table Column text and value is not visible in full?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I had a JTable and I get the value from DB, But the Table column name and Value is not visible in appropriate way..
Please guide me..!!

```
        ArrayList<QueueLogList> qLogList = dispList();

        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)qTableList.getModel();
        qTableList.setModel(model);

        model.getDataVector().removeAllElements();
        Object []row = new Object[13];
        for(QueueLogList queueLogList:qLogList){
          row[0] =  queueLogList.getQueue_no();
          row[1] =  queueLogList.getPcno();
          row[2] =  queueLogList.getPname();
          row[3] =  queueLogList.getGender();
          row[4] =  queueLogList.getAge();
          row[5] =  queueLogList.getDr_id();
          row[6] =  queueLogList.getDate();
          row[7] =  queueLogList.getTime_in();
          row[8] =  queueLogList.getTime_out();
          row[9] =  queueLogList.getAllergy();
          row[10] =  queueLogList.getWeight();
          row[11] =  queueLogList.getHeight();
          row[12] =  queueLogList.getSmoke();

          model.addRow(row);
        }
```

[image]

Comment: *"Please guide me..!!"* Drag the column wider.

Comment: You can increase the column width by dragging the column header edge.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] so we can provide the best solution for your case. Please don't post your entire code, rather to create a small runnable programm without database access (some static content in the table).

Comment: by dragging column.. DB Data still as it is.. I have disable editable table column..!

Comment: the column width being smaller than the actual length of your data in that cell would restrict how the data is presented... set the column width programmatically(instead of dragging the column header) and then check if it still looks like that.